# TinyMCE: Autosave Plugin & Ajax

Tags: php, tinymce, autosave

I am using the [Autosave Plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/autosave/):

> This plugin gives the user a warning if they made modifications to the
>   content within an editor instance but didn't submit the changes.

I use the plugin like this:

```
tinymce.init({
         selector: '#about',
         plugins: "table autoresize autosave link image",
});
```

If I change the content and try to leave the page I get a warning message as expected. However, if the user clicks the save button then the content is stored with ajax. The plugin still believes that the changes have not been submited yet.

Is there anyway how I can tell the autosave plugin that changes have been saved succesfully after the ajax call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in save function of TinyMCE's editor which will let the autosave plugin know that the content has been saved.

```
tinymce.get('about').save();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xv93x8cm/1/
For more information: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! I tried your demo but it was not working because there tinymce was not included by url. I fixed it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jr54hnzt/ However, this is still now working. If I make changes, press save, and leave the page I get a warning. Also when I alert `localStorage.getItem('tinymce-autosave-about-draft')` then this turns out to be `null`?

Comment: @Adam Take a look at my update. TinyMCE was re-saving the draft automatically on focus lost.

Comment: Thanks! But I still observe the same problem. If I change the text & click save, then I get a warning before leaving the page. Is it working for you? I have tested it on Firefox & Chrome. Also shouldn't the key be like `tinymce-autosave-draft-about`? Intuitively I would guess that `about` is the `id`? But no matter which key I used, if I try to alert them they are always null.

Comment: @Adam Did you use my new demo? It's working for me on Chrome. I also updated the prefix config to match the right key.

Comment: @Adam You have to make sure you have a draft version saved before alerting. You can find the value with Chrome&#39;s inspector. `Right click &gt; Inspect Element &gt; Application &gt; Local Storage` and check if the key exists.

Comment: Okay yes I can see the keys now. But its still not working. If I change `Hello World` to `Hi 123`   and hit save then the item `'tinymce-autosave-about-draft'` in the local storage is deleted. If I then try to close the page I get a warning. If I refresh the page then the content of `'tinymce-autosave-about-draft'` is to my surprise  `Hi 123`. If I try to leave the page then (without chaning `Hello World`) then I get no warning. Are you sure that the `'tinymce-autosave-about-draft'` item is really related to the warning message?

Comment: Also if I understood correctly, then `autosave_interval` just saves the content every `x` seconds in the localStorage right? Why would that be necessary here for testing purposes?

Comment: @Adam The interval is the number of seconds before the autosave. I changed it to `5s` for testing puroses because 30 seconds default was too long waiting.